# python auto install package

Tags: python, installation, pyqt

i'm facing a problem with python , after i created my script , there is some library i download it and i install it in my ubuntu and i used in my script , now if i give the script to client or any other user maybe he don't know what libraries are there and how to install it , i want an idea   to create install.py this file should install all libraries that script need it , is it possible ?

also other  question , if i use PYQT is there any way to convert all script to one executable file for mac and windows and linux even they did not install QT ??

Thanks advance .

Fahad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple bash script for unix that will do your job:

per module:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read p; do
  pip install $p
done < requirements.txt
```

or you can simple pass:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in `requirements.txt`, enter the modules name:

```
django
numpy
lxml
#.... so on
```

You can then run the bash script `./script.sh`

If you want to do the installation of the modules from your python script, you can use `setup`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=['module']
)
```

Comment: thanks , i will try it now , but what about other part of my question ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyQT and it's a different question.. I think it's better if you post a new question with a title including PyQT so that SO users familiar with PyQT will answer you.

Comment: check this [PyQT link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888870/how-do-i-compile-a-pyqt-script-py-to-a-single-standalone-executable-file-for).