# Easily create an executable to run code from a python distribution, without embedding

Tags: python, qt, executable

I am creating a python-qt analysis tool for windows that will be used internally in our company. I have wrapped the python code into a package that I can now distribute to my colleagues. Rather than embed a .bat file into the python scripts directory. I would like to easily create an executable that will run the python code. The script I would like to encapsulate would simply be something like:

***runner.py***

```
import myLib

myLib.run()
```

***runTool.bat***

```
python runner.py
```

I have looked at

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

[cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

But these seem more suited to wrap up all of the libraries into a stand alone executable, rather than just run the script as above with nothing embedded.

Has anyone come across this problem?

I am assuming this is how spyder.exe for example is built.

Comment: My current thinking is just to write the executable in C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compile a PyQt script (.py) to a single standalone executable file for windows (.exe) and/or linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888870/how-do-i-compile-a-pyqt-script-py-to-a-single-standalone-executable-file-for)