# How to convert PyQt code to EXE?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, cx-freeze

How can I convert PyQt4 (Python 3) code to an EXE file (without the errors)?

I have tried using: py2exe, PyInstaller, and cx_freeze. py2exe does not work, pyInstaller is unable to install (always some kind of error) and cx_freeze looks like it might work.

I can sucessfully "freeze" a program to an .exe using the following command:

```
cxfreeze --base-name Win32GUi --include-modules=sip file_name.py
```

But upon running the file (on another system) I always get an error. I fix one, a different one pops up.

Right now I am getting the following error:

[image: My stupid error]

It says DLL Error but really, it's something with the paths messed up.

It expects it will find a dll or a module in the directory of the Python installation (which does not exist because the program was compiled on another system.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compile a PyQt script (.py) to a single standalone executable file for windows (.exe) and/or linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888870/how-do-i-compile-a-pyqt-script-py-to-a-single-standalone-executable-file-for)

Comment: how does py2exe not work?

Comment: Not fully compatible with Python 3 (and PyQt4)